# Detect Collision on Child Object

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I've created an obstacle prefab. The Prefab has following hierarchy.

[image]

The player must die if he collides with Enemy. But It detects collision with parent object. I am also uploading the screen shot of property of enemy(Child Object) and Parent Object.

[image]

[image]

What should I change to let player collide with Child Object (Enemy).

Comment: Which function do you use to detect the collision?

Comment: Please provide the code, without it it's hard to determine what's the real problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The box collider on the parent object is marked as "is Trigger". Maybe your code for the collision detection for this collider is causing the player to die when colliding with the parent object.

Comment: This is the most likely problem. If he just removes the isTrigger on the Box Collider and instead enables the Polygon Collider's isTrigger on the other object, it should pretty much be fixed.